# How to display form elements when using shallow nesting in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using shallow nesting in Rails, similar to the example [here](http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/4.0/routes_resources.html#routes_nested_resources)

My routes.rb is configured with:

```
  resources :applications do
    resources :domains, shallow: true
  end
```

I have used rails scaffold to generate both models and associations, in order to add new domain to application, I can get there via

***option #1***

```
   /domains/new
```

***option #2*** via its parent resource

```
   /applications/:application_id/domains/new
```

Currently the form displays drop down to associate domain with its parent upon creation.

[image]

How can I hide this dropdown menu option if user get to the form via option 2 and display if if user get to the form via option 1?

Your thoughts is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check `params[:application_id]`:

```
<%= render 'menu' if params[:application_id].blank? %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can check if the parameter `application_id` is `nil` and set it in a hidden field if it is not `nil` coming from option #1.

Code example:

```
<%if params[:application_id].nil? %>
  display your dropdown here
<%else%>
  <%= f.hidden_field :application_id, :value => params[:application_id] %>
<%end%>
```